# brush and context for a line graph

Tags: d3.js

I am working on the line graph using brush and context see [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdQOg35LRYuYNXWSi3hK?p=preview) for what I have so far. The brushing effect is only appearing on the scale and not the line graph. I am not able to figure out how to change brushed() function so that the brushing also appears for the line chart as well.

```
function brushed(){
        console.log("brush called");
        x.domain(brush.empty() ? x1.domain() : brush.extent());
        focus.select(".line").attr("d", line);
        focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to rewrite brushed function to following to update the line chart.

```
  function brushed(){
        console.log("brush called");
        x.domain(brush.empty() ? x1.domain() : brush.extent());
        **focus.selectAll(".line").attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })**
        focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }
```

[updated plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdQOg35LRYuYNXWSi3hK?p=preview)